# Failed to start Snappy Daemon Errors

Tags: services, reboot

Please, how do I resolve the mentioned error.

I tried to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but still experiencing the same. The prompt to input password does not come.

[image]

Comment: So, you cannot login? In case you can login, post the output of the command `systemctl status snapd.service`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, o I cannot login. Please, what else can I try?